# Vim find last occurrence of

Tags: vim

In a large buffer, I'd like to scroll down to the last occurrence of pattern *pattern*.

If I am at the first occurrence, it is easy enough to search for the *pattern* `/`, reverse the *move to next occurrence* `n` with `N` and get to the last..

If I am in the middle of a sequence of occurrences.. is there a better way to jump?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

An easy way to find the last occurrence is to jump to the end and search backwards:

```
G?foo<CR>
```

In fact, there's an even easier way if you were already searching for something. Just jump to the end and *search backwards for the thing you were just searching for*:

```
GN
```

Simple as that.

**Edit**: if your search occurred on the very last line, then `GN` would skip over it to the second last occurrence. Using `ggN` would solve this problem. (And `gg?foo<CR>` for similar reasons.)

Comment: ha, I think my answer is same as your 2nd point. Didn't see that point when I wrote mine. remove mine, and up yours! +1

Comment: also I would suggest my `ggN`, even if it has one more key stroke. Because `GN` works only if the last match is not in the last line of the file. If it sits in the last line, your `N` will jump over it.

Answer (score 5):

A potentially longer solution:

```
:vim foo % | clast
```

Comment: `type clast` -> `-bash: type: clast: not found`

Comment: I am assuming `clast` is a program that should be on the $PATH? If so, I tried `type` to locate it (like `which`) but it gave me that error message.. What is `clast`?

Comment: What are you talking about? `:clast` is a vim command to jump to the last item in the quickfix list. Read `:h :clast`.

Answer (score 5):

You can try searching backward via ?

```
:1?SEARCH_PHRASE
```

Comment: Presuming ```:set wrapscan```, I prefer ```1G?search_pattern``` because it does not depend on vim.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is:

```
G/\(.\{-}\zs\(foo\)\)\{1,}<CR>
```

Comment: @StackOverflowed, what do you mean?

Comment: Sorry I Was just trying to understand it :).